# Gitignore config - how to make git aware

Tags: git

I configured git with:

```
git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore
```

I added new rules:

*.png
*.h5
*.mat

each one on a different line (consecutive lines)
then saved.

Then went to my git folder (with my source code, other files etc.). I do git add *, but git still wants to add h5 files!!. Do I have to do something else? How to make git aware of the new ignore rules before git add?

I have read that creating a .gitignore file and running the aforementioned command was enough to force git to be aware of the ignored files in a global way?

Comment: Have you already committed previous versions of these files? Git won't ignore files that it already has history for.

Comment: To be sure, are each of your rules on different lines? If not, this is where your issue happened

Comment: yes each are on different lines

Comment: I think it works now... but I would have liked a clear answer about how the "global .gitignore" works (how/when does git takes that into account)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the git cache and then add all files again

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Add all files again

```
git add .
```

And then commit changes

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

**Note:** be aware to commit all your changes before, otherwise you will lose control on all the changed files

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository) for more info

Comment: ok thanks, but what about the .gitignore file in my home folder? It it supposed to be checked by git before an add or how does it work? I cannot find a clear explanation

Comment: It seems like you already committed the files and then trying to ignore them

Comment: Machupicchu, you can read about how git ignore files work [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), particularly [this part](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_notes).